# my tokenize function does not return and complains about a corrupted doubled-link list

Tags: c

I wrote a function whose goal is to tokenize a string and return the n first tokens as an array of char*.

Initially, I have a function that tokenizes a string, but does not return anything (just to test) :

```
void tokenize_1(char *str,const int n){
  char delims[] = " \t,:";
  char *result=NULL;
  int i=0;
  char *s=malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
  strcpy(s,str);
  result = strtok(str, delims );
  while( result != NULL ) {
    i++;
    printf( "\nresult is \"%s\"", result);
    result = strtok( NULL, delims );
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Then, I'd like to return an array of n char* :

```
char **tokenize(char *str,const int n){
  char delims[] = " \t,:";
  char **result=malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
  int i=0;
  char *s=malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
  strcpy(s,str);
  result[i] = strtok(s, delims );
  while( result[i] != NULL ) {
    printf( "\nresult is \"%s\"", result[i]);
    i++;
    result[i] = strtok( NULL, delims );
  }
  printf("\n");
  return result;
}
```

The result seems correct. However my program that does not return and print a message :

> *** glibc detected *** ./program: corrupted double-linked list

What's wrong with that ? How to modify the first function to return an array of strings (as char*) ?

I am also interested in any more general advice concerning my code.

Comment: are you familiar with `strtok`?

Comment: You have more serious memory problems to worry about. And please refer to `strtok(3)` for an example.

Comment: `char *s=malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);` This is wrong, you are allocating 10 pointers, not 10 chars as you probably intended.

Comment: @RedX, I think that 2nd malloc would be casted to char*, but the size would be wrong because of the wrong sizeof. What I don't get is why take a perfectly good string, and copy it into a limited space. JCLL - at least use strncpy (and make sure it's still null terminated)

Comment: @Leeor he has to copy it as `strtok` destroys the original string.

Comment: @Redx, I didn't say he doesn't have to copy it, just not into a potentially too small of a space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few errors with your memory allocations.eg:

```
char **result=malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
char *s=malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
```

These should be like:

```
char **result=malloc(n*sizeof(char)*MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH);
char *s=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(str) + 1);
```

also u need to correct this condition:

```
while( result[i] != NULL )
```

it should stop after n tokens are generated.

```
while( (result[i] != NULL) && (i < n)  )
```

here is the what i tried with your function:

```
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH 100

char **tokenize(char *str,const int n){
  char delims[] = " \t,:";
  char **result=malloc(n*sizeof(char)*MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH);
  int i=0;
  char *s=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(str) + 1);
  strcpy(s,str);
  result[i] = strtok(s, delims );
  while( (result[i] != NULL) && (i < n)  ) {
  //printf( "\nresult is \"%s\"", result[i]);
  i++;
  result[i] = strtok( NULL, delims );
  }
  printf("\n");
  return result;
}

int main(){
char **result;
int i;
int number_of_tokens = 4;
result = tokenize("hi i am: abhipranay,a\tchauhan",number_of_tokens);
for(i=0;i < number_of_tokens; i++){
    printf("%s\n",(result[i]));
}
return 0;
}
```